# Creating Session Data

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Here's my function. I'm trying to create some new session data based on the input from a form.
The user data is being created (i.e. `user_url`), however the value for that, `$set_url` is not being stored...

What am I doing wrong? This is an ajax function, that works as it should. However, i need to store and print (i.e. `$data['web_url']`) in the success view.

```
public function web_embed()
{
    $set_url = $this->input->post('web_address'); // grabs web URL entered in form - creates variable        
    $this->session->set_userdata('user_url', $set_url); // set user url session

    $data['web_url'] = $this->session->userdata('user_url'); // grab session                
    $data['iframe_content'] = 'partials/web_url_success'; // displays view

    if ($this->input->post('ajax')) { // is 'ajax' variable from jQuery function exists, load:   
        $this->load->view($data['iframe_content'], $data);           
    }
}
```

**Please Note** I have done a `print_r($this->session->userdata);` and `[user_url] =>` is there...just no value. I printed this on the success view.

Comment: does the variable `$set_url` gets correct value. I mean to ask what do you get when you print $set_url

Comment: Look at my "Please Note" comment above... I get `[user_url] =>`, but it has no value. So to me, it looks like the input->post() is not working...but not sure why

Comment: put `print_r($_POST)`; before of `$set_url = $this->input->post('web_address');` and check the values

Comment: Here's what was displayed...so seems I'm getting value...agh! `Array ( [url] => http://www.domain.com [ajax] => 1 )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, comments above answered my own problem...I forgot I'm posting from the jQuery ajax function, not the form itself. So the input name is different...

Changed
`$set_url = $this->input->post('web_address');`

to:

`$set_url = $this->input->post('url');`

and it worked!!!